# InMemoryUploadFile processing

Tags: django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I have a question about Django InMemoryUploadedFile processing.

I tried to upload a simple csv file whose content is as below

> username,name
>
> user1,user1

I use the snippet below to get the file data and save it locally (Django REST framework)

```
def put(self, request, filename, format=None):
    file_obj = request.data['file']
    path = default_storage.save('demo.csv',ContentFile(file_obj.read()))
```

However, the result file has content:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryJaXsjE9oec2QW6jz Content-Disposition: form-data; name="demo.csv"; filename="demo.csv" Content-Type: text/csv
>   username,user user1,user
>   ------WebKitFormBoundaryJaXsjE9oec2QW6jz--

I use react-dropzone Dropzone to send the file from frontend server.

```
class UserUpload extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onDrop = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
      const file = acceptedFiles[0];
      const payload = superagent.put(`${API_ROOT}/user-upload/${file.name}`).attach(file.name, file);
      payload.end(callback)
    }
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}>
        <p>Drop file here</p>
      </Dropzone>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there any way that I can retrieve the csv file data only without the header and footer above? My purpose is to read the csv file, is there a way to read data directly without saving first?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this API Class,

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class CSVUploadAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        for file in request.FILES.values():
            with open(file.name, 'wb') as file_obj:
                file_obj.write(file.read())
                file_obj.close()
        return Response("File uploaded")
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Hmm it seems like the result is exactly the same as before when there are still header and footer attached to the csv file. Do I need to attach headers to the request or similar? I have added the code I use to send the file from frontend server to the question

Comment: Oh the problem is with the parser classes FileUploadParser. I just notice you did not include this in your code. Removing this part solve the problem.

Comment: I checked my result, and I didn't find any problem at all. If any error occurred let me know please...

Comment: oh.. seems like you got the answer, and glad to hear that :)

Comment: Let me just say again that `parser_classes` variable should not be defined in the  class or its parents